# How to Insert Related Posts Inside WordPress Post Content

Tags: php

**i want to show related post in inside post for example after 3 paragraph, this code is after content is that possible without plugin if yes, so how can do, plz guide with code.**.

```
 <ul class="relatedpost">
    <?php
                        $related = get_posts( array( 'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID), 'numberposts' => 3, 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) ) );
                        if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) {
                        setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                <li>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                </li>
                             <?php }
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in between", and what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: i want to show related post in inside post for example after 3 paragraph, this code is after content

Comment: There's a few questions about doing this for adverts, e.g. [Inserting ads within content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215732/inserting-ads-within-content), [Add an advert every nth Paragraph](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/252983/add-an-advert-every-nth-paragraph), [How do I show google ads between post content?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142143/how-do-i-show-google-ads-between-post-content). They all use the_content filters. I don't know which is the best one.

Comment: It also depends on whether you're using the Block Editor or the Classic Editor (or a builder), and what your content looks like. It's likely that using either a custom block or a shortcode might be the easiest, one-size-fits-all option since you can manually add them no matter what Editor you're using and no matter if the content varies between posts.